# How to save iterations in a loop as follows?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I use two for loop to go through two arrays. I have set the conditions to print me only those that meet my conditions.

the individual positions in are in the array comb_x and comb_y. this results in conditions in the for loop

This is fine and works as it should.

This my code

```
import os
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
    
    
a=np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
b=np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
z1=np.array([1, 1])
z2=np.array([1, 1])
comb_x=np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
comb_y=np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
for (j), (k) in zip(a,b):
    z1[:]=0
    z1[:j]=1
    x12=z1
    z2[:]=0
    z2[:k]=1
    y12=z2  
    #print(x12,y12)
                    
    for (h),(n),(r) in zip(comb_x,comb_y,np.arange(0,4)):
        if x12[h]==1 and y12[n]==1:
            print('pravda',x12,y12)
```

My output sorts those numbers by values

my output:

```
[1 0] [1 0]
[1 0] [1 1]
[1 0] [1 1]
[1 1] [1 0]
[1 1] [1 0]
[1 1] [1 1]
[1 1] [1 1]
[1 1] [1 1]
[1 1] [1 1]
```

I need them to appear as well as follow in each iteration

required output

```
[1 0] [1 0]
[1 0] [1 1]
[1 1] [1 0]
[1 1] [1 1]
[1 0] [1 1]
[1 1] [1 1]
[1 1] [1 0]
[1 1] [1 1]
[1 1] [1 1]
```

To make it easier to see, I'll show below what the individual iterations and their results should look like

first iteration:

```
[1 0] [1 0]
[1 0] [1 1]
[1 1] [1 0]
[1 1] [1 1]
```

second iteration:

```
[1 0] [1 1]
[1 1] [1 1]
```

third iteration:

```
[1 1] [1 0]
[1 1] [1 1]
```

fourth iteration:

```
[1 1] [1 1]
```

But as you can see, it does not save them by iteration, but sorts them in ascending order by value

Could it be arranged according to iterations so that it is still a numpy array?